# Unable to install Scala plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-plugin, karate

we have written all our karate api automation scripts in eclipse and we have decided to enhance our framework with performance test using Gatling script, unfortunately we are unable to install Scala plugin, facing below installation error. Please help here!! thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9wso.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5msnt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSrdH.png)
[image]

Comment: The **ScalaIDE** for **Eclipse** has been deprecated and abandoned for the last five years or so. If you want to use **Eclipse** you need to do it through **metals**: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/eclipse/

Comment: There is very little code you need to write in Scala, so if you can manage with just Maven, I recommend that option. Also consider IntelliJ community edition.

Comment: Also, since Gatling 3.7, Gatling also supports Java and Kotlin. So you don't have to go with Scala to write Gatling tests unless you really want to.